# TimePicker and DatePicker

Tags: android

I have made TimePicker Dialog and DatePicker Dialog:

TimePicker Dialog:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current time as the default values for the picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

// Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
// Do something with the time chosen by the user
}
}
```

DatePicker Dialog:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
// Do something with the date chosen by the user
}
}
```

My problem is that when I pick time or date I want to save it in specific textField. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it callback method onDateSet/onTimeSet.

If by textField, you mean textView/EditText in your xml layout.

`((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextField)).setText(FORMATTED_DATE);`

For formatting, you can do something like this

```
String.format("%d-%d-%d",day,month,year)
```

Something lke that